# when setting notification status bar for downloading file , phone gets hang

Tags: android, notifications

Thanks for taking time to read this question,

When i show notification status bar on android phone it shows properly,

But When i  update the status bar continuously ,
Phone get hang ,
even some time it gets restart.
For Downloading file from Server i am using Loopj Library.

Here is my code to download any file from Server:-

```
public void RetriveFileFromServer(RequestParams params, File filePath) {
    mNotifyManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Document Download")
            .setContentText("Download in progress...")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.download).build();
    mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());


    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.get(URL, params, new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(filePath) {


        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File file) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
            Log.e("Success", file.getPath());
            mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
                    .setProgress(0, 0, false);
            mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, File
                file) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
            Log.e("Fail", file.getPath() + " failure");
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(long bytesWritten, long totalSize) {


            long progressPercentage = (long) 100 * bytesWritten / totalSize;
            mBuilder.setContentText("Persent: " + progressPercentage);
            mBuilder.setProgress(100, (int) progressPercentage, false);
            mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: did you check the error logs and try to debug  ? any error ?

Comment: I checked the log..there is no error